# react-bootstrap set external link without active

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

When I click on Google it opens in a new tab that's fine. But when I come back to my site, the link to Google is being set to active.

```
<Nav defaultActiveKey="1">
  <Nav.Link href="/home" eventKey="1">Home</Nav.Link>
  <Nav.Link href="https://google.com" target="_blank">Google</Nav.Link>
  <Nav.Link href="/service" eventKey="2">Service</Nav.Link>
</Nav>
```

How can I not apply active for external link like I have? If I move that link outside Nav it will be fine. But in my case, I have to put inside the Nav.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navs/), you can set `active` to false:

```
<Nav.Link href="https://google.com" target="_blank" active={false}>
  Google
</Nav.Link>
```